# Rails undefined method `product_ids' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Beginner error here... trying to create a shopping cart for users.  I get this error, "undefined method `product_ids' for nil:NilClass", when I add a product to cart.

**ShoppingCart Model:**

```
    class ShoppingCart < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :user
      belongs_to :order
      belongs_to :product_id
    end
```

**Product Model:**

```
    class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :books
      belongs_to :user
      has_many :orders
      has_many :shopping_carts
    end
```

**ProductSelectionsController**

```
    class ProductSelectionsController < ApplicationController
      def create
        current_user.shopping_cart.product_ids << params[:product_id]
        current_user.shopping_cart.save
        redirect_to :back
      end
    end
```

**ShoppingCart Migration:**

```
    class CreateShoppingCarts < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        create_table :shopping_carts do |t|
          t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
          t.references :order, index: true, foreign_key: true
          t.string :orderstatus
          t.integer :quantity
          t.text :product_ids, array: true, default: []

          t.timestamps null: false
        end
      end
    end
```

**Add to Cart link Product.show:**

```
<%= link_to "Add to cart", product_selections_path(product_ids: @product.id), method: :post %>
```

**Initialize cart in User.rb**

```
after_initialize do 
 if shopping_cart.nil? 
  shopping_cart = ShoppingCart.create
 end
end
```

I know it's right under my nose, what am I missing?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you want `belongs_to :product` not `product_id`

Comment: What's up with the down vote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`current_user.shopping_cart` is nil, but you invoked a method on it anyways. There is no evidence that you've tried to assign a value to it in the code you've posted, and Rails will not automatically assign a value to the variable for you.

---

RE your edits:

```
after_initialize do 
 if shopping_cart.nil? 
  shopping_cart = ShoppingCart.create
 end
end
```

That isn't how you assign to member variables in Ruby. You're assigning to a local variable called `shopping_cart` which has absolutely nothing to do with `self.shopping_cart`. If you want to assign to `self.shopping_cart`, you cannot omit `self.`

You need to use `self.shopping_cart = ShoppingCart.create`.

Comment: So you're saying my error is coming from the initialize method in my user.rb file?

Comment: Yes. **You never set `current_user.shopping_cart`**. You assign a new shopping cart to a temporary local variable, which is then immediately discarded.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  My apologies for the lack of evidence.  Your advice solved the problem.